# How to reverse text in EXCEL without VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to reverse long text in excel using without using VBA.

My text like this,

```
0000 12341252 LONGTEST 39192329 3 ABECIEEE 8899123 44 CCCCCCC 20%
```

I want to reverse this text like this,

```
%02 CCCCCCC 44 3219988 EEEICEBA 3 92329193 TSETGNOL 25214321 0000
```

After all research i found something and try to reverse with this formula

```
=TRIM(CONCAT(IFERROR(MID(A3;(LEN(A3)+1)-COLUMN($A:$AK);1);"")))
```

Result is

**%02 CCCCCCC 44 3219988 EEEICEBA 3 923**

In my case problem is this I cannot add anything in the VBA part when I research i found some function which I can add as a module in excel and use it but I need to make this with formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `COLUMN($A:$AK)` is limiting it to a fixed number of characters.

Use:

```
 =CONCAT(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)))+1,1))
```

this is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

I use INDEX over INDIRECT as INDIRECT is Volatile and will re-calc unnecessarily.

It is now dynamic and will take any size string.

[image]

Comment: Better solution given index over indirect

Comment: Scott Sir, thanks a bunch, use of `INDEX` over `INDIRECT` really helpful, learnt this approaches from following your solutions!

Answer (score 3):

```
{=TEXTJOIN("",1,MID(B5,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B5))-(LEN(B5)+1)),1))}
```

Array formula which must be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know, this is an old question but thought I'd share two more options:

**Formula:**

I suppose this is looking after @Scott_Craner's answer but using `SEQUENCE()`:

```
=CONCAT(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-SEQUENCE(LEN(A1))+1,1))
```

Or, for a range of cells:

```
=MAP(A1:A9,LAMBDA(s,CONCAT(MID(s,LEN(s)-SEQUENCE(LEN(s))+1,1))))
```

**Python:**

With the new `PY()` function you could also use:

```
xl("A1")[::-1]
```

Or, for a range of cells:

```
[s[::-1] for s in xl("A1:A9")[0]]
```